# setting axis labels in axes from matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying the following code to plot some graphs:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 20))
for idx, col in enumerate(['Pclass', 'Sex']):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, idx+1)
    _ = ax.set(ylabel='Counts')
    _ = sns.countplot(x=col, hue='Survived', data=full, ax=ax)
```

*The output I'm getting is:*
[image: Link to the graphs here]

As you can see the `y` label is set as the `seaborn` `countplot` default label `'count'`, but I want to change it to `'Counts'`. I've tried the `axes` method `set_ylabel` and set with `ylabel` argument and got no changes in the graphs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following, changing the `ylabel` after plotting

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 20))
for idx, col in enumerate(['Pclass', 'Sex']):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, idx+1)
    sns.countplot(x=col, hue='Survived', data=full, ax=ax)
    ax.set_ylabel('Counts')
```